Add "identifiers" to questions for printing
So, I have this code that lets me number questions/ exercises according to chapters ("Exercise 1.1", etc). I have one count to "identify" the question and one count to display the question (this is so that I can print the solution in the appendix). I want to somehow link these counts. The "id" count is called "QuestionID" and the display count is called "questionDisplay". Here is the MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtcolorbox{exercises}{%
    top=4mm,
    before skip=7mm,after skip=4mm,
    boxsep=5mm,
    frame empty,
    colback=yellow!20,
    breakable
}

% \newtheorem{question}{Exercise}
\newcounter{questionDisplay}[chapter]
\setcounter{questionDisplay}{0}
\newcounter{QuestionID}
\setcounter{QuestionID}{0}
\newenvironment{question}{
    \stepcounter{questionDisplay}\stepcounter{QuestionID}
    \textbf{Exercise \thechapter.\thequestionDisplay.}\itshape
}

\newcommand{\Exercise}[2]{
\begin{question}
    #1
\end{question}
\vspace{2mm}
\expandafter\gdef\csname answer:\theQuestionID\endcsname{#2}
}
\newcommand{\PrintExerciseSolutions}[3]{
\begin{exercises}
\newcount\i
\i = #2
\newcount \j
\j = 1
\loop
\textbf{Solution~ #1.\the\j.}
\csname answer:\the\i\endcsname\ \par\vspace{0.5cm}
\advance \i 1
\advance \j 1
\ifnum \i < \numexpr#3 +1\relax
\repeat
\end{exercises}
}%

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{The start}

\begin{exercises}
    \Exercise{Hello??}{Does this work?}
    \Exercise{This is the second one}{Does it still not work?}
\end{exercises}


\chapter{The second one}


\begin{exercises}
    \Exercise{This is exercises in different chapters}{Chap 2}
    \Exercise{Another question}{This answer is unique.}
\end{exercises}

\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 1}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{1}{1}{2}

\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 2}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{2}{3}{4}



\end{document}

So I want \PrintExerciseSolutions{2} to print the exercise solutions to chapter 2. As of now, I need to manually input which questions are in chapter 2 for this to work (question 2-4) and this setup can easily go wrong. If I do \PrintExerciseSolutions{4}{4}{4}, then the solution to exercise 2.2 gets printed as:

So if I miscount and think say there are 40 exercises in chapter 1 when it is in fact 42, then I may accidentally print the solution to "Exercise 1.41" under chapter 2 as "Solution 2.1", which would be very confusing. So instead I want the command to be like this: \PrintExerciseSolutions{<chapter>}.
As a side note: Later I want to change it to \PrintExerciseSolutions[<exercise list>]{<chapter>}. For example:\PrintExerciseSolutions[2,4,6]{2} which should print solutions to exercises 2.2, 2.4 and 2.6. So it would be nice to have some way of identifying the QuestionID with the question number within a chapter as well.
So what I need is some way to link the "QuestionID" to what chapter it appears in (and also what number that question is in that chapter). How can I do this? Can I somehow use the chapter count? And what about the question number?

Define a property list for each chapter containing the solutions. The property list is allocated as soon as a solution is provided in the chapter, so we can check whether the chapter either doesn't exist or has no exercise.
You can also state exercises without solution by leaving the second argument blank and such exercises will be ignored in the solutions.
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtcolorbox{exercises}{%
    top=4mm,
    before skip=7mm,after skip=4mm,
    boxsep=5mm,
    frame empty,
    colback=yellow!20,
    breakable
}

% \newtheorem{question}{Exercise}
\newcounter{questionDisplay}[chapter]

\NewDocumentCommand{\question}{m}{%
    \par\refstepcounter{questionDisplay}%
    \textbf{Exercise \thechapter.\thequestionDisplay.} \textit{#1}\par
    \addvspace{2mm}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Exercise}{mm}
 {
  \question{#1}
  \prop_if_exist:cF { g_vebjorn_solutions_ \arabic{chapter} _prop}
   {
    \prop_new:c { g_vebjorn_solutions_ \arabic{chapter} _prop }
   }
  \prop_gput:cee { g_vebjorn_solutions_ \arabic{chapter} _prop } { \arabic{questionDisplay} }
   {
    \__vebjorn_print_solution:nn { \thechapter.\thequestionDisplay } { \exp_not:n {#2} }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintExerciseSolutions}{om}
 {
  \prop_if_exist:cTF { g_vebjorn_solutions_#2_prop }
   {
    \begin{exercises}
    \IfNoValueTF {#1}
     {% print all exercises
      \int_step_inline:nn { \prop_count:c { g_vebjorn_solutions_#2_prop } }
       {
        \__vebjorn_solutions_check:nn { #2 } { ##1 }
       }
     }
     {% else, a selection
      \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
       {
        \__vebjorn_solutions_check:nn { #2 } { ##1 }
       }
     }
    \end{exercises}
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { vebjorn/solutions } { chapter-no-exercise } { #2 }
   }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__vebjorn_solutions_text_tl

\msg_new:nnn { vebjorn/solutions } { chapter-no-exercise }
 {
  Chapter~#1~has~no~exercise~(or~doesn't~exist)~\msg_line_context:
 }
\msg_new:nnn { vebjorn/solutions } { exercise-not-exist }
 {
  Exercise~#1.#2~does~not~exist~\msg_line_context:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__vebjorn_print_solution:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF {#2}
   {
    \par\textbf{Solution~#1}~#2\par\addvspace{5mm}
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__vebjorn_solutions_check:nn
 {
  \prop_get:cnNTF { g_vebjorn_solutions_#1_prop} { #2 } \l__vebjorn_solutions_text_tl
   {
    \tl_use:N \l__vebjorn_solutions_text_tl
   }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnnn { vebjorn/solutions } { exercise-not-exist } { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{The start}

\begin{exercises}
\Exercise{Hello??}{Does this work?}
\Exercise{This exercise has no solution}{}
\Exercise{This is the second one}{Does it still not work?}
\end{exercises}

\chapter{The second one}

\begin{exercises}
\Exercise{This is exercises in different chapters}{Chap 2}
\Exercise{Another question}{This answer is unique.}
\Exercise{Foo}{Baz}
\end{exercises}

\backmatter

\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 1}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{1}

\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 2}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{2}

\section{Solutions to selected exercises in chapter 2}

\PrintExerciseSolutions[1,3,8]{2}

\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 3}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{3}

\end{document}


The console output warning that exercise 2.8 doesn't exist and that chapter 3 has no exercises (or doesn't exist).
Package vebjorn/solutions Warning: Exercise 2.8 does not exist on line 127


Package vebjorn/solutions Warning: Chapter 3 has no exercise (or doesn't
(vebjorn/solutions)                exist) on line 131


With help from Chat GPT I arrived at this:
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtcolorbox{exercises}{%
    top=4mm,
    before skip=7mm,after skip=4mm,
    boxsep=5mm,
    frame empty,
    colback=yellow!20,
    breakable
}

\newcounter{questionDisplay}[chapter]
\newcounter{QuestionID}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnnn { Exercise } { not found } 
    { Exercise(s)~not~found! } 
    { Exercise(s)~\tl_use:N \l_missing_list_tl~in~chapter~\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int~could~not~be~found. }

\seq_new:N \g_exercises_seq

\newcommand{\Exercise}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{questionDisplay}%
  \refstepcounter{QuestionID}%
  \noindent\textbf{Exercise \thechapter.\thequestionDisplay.} \par \itshape
  \expandafter\gdef\csname answer:\thechapter.\thequestionDisplay\endcsname{#2}%
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_exercises_seq { \thechapter , \thequestionDisplay , \theQuestionID }%
  #1 \par \normalfont
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintExerciseSolutions}{o m}{%
  \group_begin:%
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {#2} % Chapter number
  \iow_term:x {Printing~solutions~for~chapter~\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}%
  \begin{exercises}%
    \bool_set_false:N \l_tmp_bool
    \tl_clear:N \l_missing_list_tl

\IfNoValueTF{#1}{
% Fill in code
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_exercises_seq
      {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { , } {##1}
        \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1} } = { #2 }
        {
          \textbf{Solution~\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}.\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2}.}
          \csname answer:\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {1}.\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2}\endcsname
          \par\vspace{0.5cm}
        }
        {
          \bool_set_true:N \l_tmp_bool
          \tl_put_right:Nx \l_missing_list_tl { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {2}, }
        }
      }
}{
      \clist_map_inline:nn {#1}
      {
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int {##1} % Exercise number
        \cs_if_exist:cTF {answer:\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int.\int_use:N \l_tmpb_int}
        {
          \textbf{Solution~\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int.##1.}
          \csname answer:\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int.\int_use:N \l_tmpb_int\endcsname
          \par\vspace{0.5cm}
        }
        {
          \bool_set_true:N \l_tmp_bool
          \tl_put_right:Nx \l_missing_list_tl { ##1, }
        }
      }
      \bool_if:NT \l_tmp_bool
      {
        \msg_warning:nn { Exercise } { not found }
      }
    }
  \end{exercises}%
  \group_end:%
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{The start}

\begin{exercises}
    \Exercise{Hello??}{Does this work?}
    \Exercise{This is the second one}{Does it still not work?}
\end{exercises}

\chapter{The second one}

\begin{exercises}
    \Exercise{This is exercises in different chapters}{Chap 2}
    \Exercise{Another question}{This answer is unique.}
\end{exercises}

\backmatter
\chapter{Appendix}
\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 1}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{1}

\section{Solutions to exercises in chapter 2}

\PrintExerciseSolutions[{1,4}]{2}

\PrintExerciseSolutions{2}

\end{document}

Which correctly gives:

And:

for exercise 2.4 which doesn't exist.
